# Sublime coloring everything between brackets different color than outside

Tags: sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

In a Sublime Syntax file, I can color all hard brackets and everything inside using a command like this:

```
- match: '\[.*?\]'
  scope: keyword.control
```

If I want to color everything inside the bracket a different color, I tried something like this:

```
- match: '\['
  scope: variable.function
  comment: Images
  push:
    - meta_scope: constant.numeric
    - match: \]
      pop: true
```

The problem is it will color the last bracket the same color as the inside. Any idea how to make the last bracket the same color as the starting bracket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Syntax documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html), it says this (emphasis mine):

> - **meta_scope**. This assigns the given scope to all text within this context, including the patterns that push the context onto the stack and pop it off.
> - **meta_content_scope**. As above, but ***does not apply to the text that triggers the context*** (e.g., in the above string example, the content scope would not get applied to the quote characters).

In your second example, you're using `meta_scope`, which causes the match that pops the context off the stack to have this scope applied as well. If you swap it to `meta_content_scope`, this doesn't happen. However in that case no specific scope is applied to the `]` character at all, so it will appear the same as the standard text color.

In order to fix that, you can also apply the same scope to it as to the one that originally pushed the context. For example:

```yaml
- match: '\['
  scope: variable.function
  comment: Images
  push:
    - meta_content_scope: constant.numeric
    - match: \]
      scope: variable.function
      pop: true
```

Technically if all you're after is the color, just the `scope` is required and will probably do what you want. However it's "cleaner" to use `meta_content_scope` as well, to avoid the possibility that it might still be colored based on the wrong scope.